# Можно ли изменить логику метода с помощью рефлексии?

Tags: java

Могу ли я добавить логику внутрь метода с помощью рефлексии? Мне надо мини фреймворк сделать по валидации. Я нахожу поле которое помечено аннотацией потом нахожу сеттер этого поля и хочу туда внедрить логику валидации параметра метода.

Comment: Внутри - нет, не можете. Но можете автоматически сгенерировать класс-декоратор, реализующий тот же самый интерфейс (кажется, так Spring работает или работал).

Comment: А вообще - гуглите AOP (аспектно-ориентированное программирование)

Comment: спасибо большое